# AppSync offline - "JSON5: invalid character '&' at 2:3"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm trying to implement a GrapgQL API described in following tutorial.

[GraphQL API using Serverless + AWS AppSync + DynamoDB + Lambda resolvers + Cognito. [Part 1]](https://medium.com/@facundofasciolo/graphql-api-using-serverless-aws-appsync-dynamodb-lambda-resolvers-cognito-part-1-8ec947614b86)

I'm using the current versions of serverless and other involved dependencies. (see package.json) My OS is Manjaro 5.4.2-1.

My problem is that the common-response.vtl is not working **offline**. Deployed to aws everything is working fine.

```
* file: mapping-templates/common-response.vtl *
## If there is a datasource invocation error, we choose to raise the same error
## the field data will be set to null.
#if($ctx.error)
  $util.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type, $ctx.result)
#end

$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

```
* file: lambda-functions/book/listBooks/index.js *
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log({event});

  const books = [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'First mocked book'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Second mocked book'
    }
  ];
  console.log(books);
  return books;
};
```

the lambda resolver log looks good

```
* console *
Serverless: dynamoDB started: http://localhost:62226/
listening for subscriptions at: ws://localhost:38643/
Serverless: AppSync started: http://localhost:62222/graphql
Serverless: Starting Offline: local/eu-west-1.

Serverless: Routes for listBooks:
Serverless: POST /{apiVersion}/functions/sls-appsync-demo-local-listBooks/invocations

Serverless: Offline [HTTP] listening on http://localhost:3001
Serverless: Enter "rp" to replay the last request
{ event: { arguments: {} } }
[
  { id: '1', title: 'First mocked book' },
  { id: '2', title: 'Second mocked book' }
]
{ event: { arguments: {} } }
[
  { id: '1', title: 'First mocked book' },
  { id: '2', title: 'Second mocked book' }
]
```

but the response in postman is an error

```
* postman *
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "JSON5: invalid character '&' at 2:3",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "listBooks"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "listBooks": null
    }
}
```

When I paste the logged response into the resolver, postman prints out the expected result. I also tried to put the result in an error response.

```
* file: mapping-templates/common-response.vtl *
## If there is a datasource invocation error, we choose to raise the same error
## the field data will be set to null.
#if($ctx.error)
  $util.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type, $ctx.result)
#end

$util.error($ctx.result)
```

and the result is there ...

```
* postman *
{
    "data": {
        "listBooks": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "First mocked book"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "Second mocked book"
                }
            ],
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "listBooks"
            ],
            "errorType": null,
            "data": null,
            "errorInfo": null
        }
    ]
}
```

so something is wrong with the toJson function in combination with appsync offline but I have no idea how to solve this issue

complete example code: [github repo](https://github.com/kingkomg/sls-appsync-example)

Comment: Do you have customer resolver?

Comment: I added the lambda function which resolves the request with a mock response

Comment: "so something is wrong with the toJson function in combination with appsync offline".Yes, you are right, look at this https://github.com/aheissenberger/serverless-appsync-offline/issues/40

Comment: Yes, replacing the velocityjs lib is the solution for now. Thank you so much.

Comment: please let me know if replacing the velocityjs lib worked for you.

Comment: I had several other little problems since this one but could fix them all. So yes the workaround works and everything is running offline and online.